# Physics and Math animated video

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to start and create math and physics animated video. Do you guys have any suggestions on the software to use? I have a Wacom tablet to draw but I am not sure I want to draw myself or instead to somehow use tools that do stuff like drawing graphs, equations etc..

So any suggestions and ideas will be precious.

P.S. It would be nice to have something that includes the latex features

P.P.S. Some introductory tutorial would be also useful

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? What do you need the software to do? And what is your budget? Also, it might be worth doing a search of this site, because similar questions to this get asked at least weekly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoGebra Math Apps](https://www.geogebra.org/) is an awesome option to do 2-D and 3-D static pictures and animations.

You may do it on-line, or download individual applications into your PC or tablet / smartphone.

It partially supports LaTeX and is for free.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use MS office.

You have of course Excel that can make the graphs but assigning some data.

On PowerPoint, you can make animations, import different assets, and export to video. And there are some online Add ons to import LaTeX.